# Calling a function before declaring it using function expression works. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared two functions using function expression `innerone` and `innertwo`. I first declared `innerone` and after that `innertwo`. Inside `innerone` I am calling `innertwo` function. But my concern is that I am declaring `innertwo` after `innerone` using function expression which means `innertwo` is not hoisted. So why these functions work in this order? Is it mandatory to change their order?

Here is code

```
var one = function () {
    var innerone = function () {
        innertwo();
    },

    innertwo = function () {
        console.log('innertwo');
    };

    return {
        innerone: innerone
    };
};

var o = new one();
o.innerone();
```

Comment: It works because you are calling `innertwo` after it was defined (when you call `innerone`). If you'd directly place a call to `innertwo` before `var innertwo = function() ....` it would throw an error.

Comment: It works because when you create a new instance of the object and `innerone` is returned `innertwo` already exists. But I don't think you should be using `new` since it seems you're using the module pattern, just use `var o = one()`.

Comment: Why do this in the first place?  There are much clearer ways to end up with the same result.

Comment: @jfriend00 for example which ways?

Comment: @x4f4r - simpler ways provided in an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working because innerone is called only when you call it. And by the time it's called innertwo is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You asked in your comment for simpler ways to write this code, so here are a couple simpler ways.  The first still returns the structure and can be just called as a function without `new`.  The second adds a property to the function object, but still preserves the private function `innertwo()`.  The second option looks the cleanest to me.

Option 1:

```
function one() {
    function innertwo() {
        console.log('innertwo');
    }

    return {
        innerone: function() {
            innertwo();
        }
    };
}

var o = one();    // new is not needed here
o.innerone();
```

Option 2:

```
function one() {
    function innertwo() {
        console.log('innertwo');
    }

    this.innerone = function () {
        innertwo();
    };
};


var o = new one();
o.innerone();
```